# Variable externa pierde su valor al salir de la función typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, variables, variables-globales, filereader

tengo el siguiente código typescript:

```
var base;
readFile(file, function(e) {        
    base = e.target.result;            
});    
alert(base);
```

La variable "base" obtiene su valor dentro de la función readFile, y si hago un alert() dentro de readFile puedo ver su valor sin ningún problema, pero si quiero ver el valor de "base" fuera de la función readFile me devuelve indefinido.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que la variable base mantenga el valor asignado fuera de la función readFile?

Acá les dejo también el contenido de la función readFile, la cual funciona perfectamente:

```
function readFile(file, onLoadCallback){
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = onLoadCallback;
      reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No pierde el valor, solo se está usando antes de tenerlo.

Eso se debe a que la función `readAsText()` lee el archivo de forma asíncrona por eso se pasa una función callback que se ejecutará cuando la lectura termine `onload`.

La secuencia de ejecución sería así:

```
    // 1. se declara la variable
    var base; 
    // 2. se llama la función readFile
    // la función readFile empieza a leer el archivo de forma asíncrona
    // y el programa principal sigue su ejecución secuencial
    readFile(file, function(e) {        
        base = e.target.result;            
    });    
    // 3. base es undefined porque la lectura no ha terminado 
    // por lo tanto su valor no ha sido asignado
    alert(base);

    // 4. En algún momento la lectura del archivo termina y la función callback
    // se ejecuta y la variable base toma su valor
```

El valor de `base` está disponible hasta que se ejecuta la función callback.

```
readFile(file, function(e) {        
            base = e.target.result; 
            alert(base);           
 });
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, tu respuesta me ayudó mucho a entender el problema y ya encontré una solución

Answer (score 1):

Solucioné el problema siguiendo las indicaciones que me dieron, de la siguiente manera:

```
var file = event.target.files[0];  
var base;  
base = readFileAsDataURL(file);
async function readFileAsDataURL(file) {
  let result_base64 = await new Promise((resolve) => {
      let fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = (e) => resolve(fileReader.result);
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });          
  return result_base64;
}

alert(btoa(base))
```

De esta forma se hace la ejecución de la función callback y luego puedo retornar el valor.
Luego decodifico el objeto "base" y listo, obtengo el string base64 que quería.