# Crear un arreglo de imágenes usando input file y notificar cuando todas estén cargadas Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Quiero crear un arreglo de imágenes que luego subiré a mi base de datos, por lo que estoy utilizando un `input` de tipo `file` pero al momento de crear el arreglo el primer elemento no lo agrega y además como transformar dicho arreglo en un json.

**Html**

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <img *ngFor='let url of urls' [src]="url">
    <input type="file" (change)="onselect($event)" multiple>
</div>"
```

**Componente**

```
urls=[];

onselect(e){
  if(e.target.files){
    var filesAmount = e.target.files.length;
    for(let i=0; i < filesAmount; i++){
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[i]);
      reader.onload=(events:any)=>{
        this.urls.push(events.target.result);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: No queda claro el problema, el código funciona, puedes verlo aquí https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kgtm1g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Lobos El tema esta en que si agregas un `console.log` del arreglo cuando agregas el primer elemento al arreglo me lo arroja vacío, y luego solo me muestra el ultimo elemento cargado.

Comment: Revisa esta respuesta, ahí se explica lo que está pasando https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/403893/variable-externa-pierde-su-valor-al-salir-de-la-funci%c3%b3n-typescript/403936#403936  si pones el `console.log` después de `this.urls.push(events.target.result);` imprimirá todas las url.

Comment: @Lobos entiendo que es un tema de sincronismo y el ejemplo mediante el cual resolviste la problemática aplica para un elemento que subís y es allí donde se me vuelve a presentar el inconveniente de como adaptar esta solución cuando quiero subir múltiples imágenes y estas que se agreguen en un arreglo de imagenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrego código de ejemplo donde se notifica cuando todas las imágenes han sido cargadas.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
    import { Subject } from "rxjs";
    
    @Component({
      selector: "my-app",
      templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
      styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      urls = [];
      // observable para notificar cuando las imágenes se carguen
      private notificarCargaCompleta = new Subject();
    
      constructor() {
        // suscripcion al observable
        this.notificarCargaCompleta.subscribe(r => {
          // código a ejecutar cuando las imágenes estén cargadas
          console.log("imagenes cargadas");
          console.log(this.urls);
        });
      }
    
      onselect(e) {
        if (e.target.files) {
          var filesAmount = e.target.files.length;
          for (let i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[i]);
            reader.onload = (events: any) => {
              this.urls.push(events.target.result);
    
              // si el arreglo ya tiene las tres imagenes
              // notificar la carga completa
              if (this.urls.length == filesAmount) {
                this.notificarCargaCompleta.next();
              }
            };
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

[Demo en vivo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kgtm1g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, era justo lo que estaba necesitando!